# Configuring file path dynamically in Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, war

I have database.properties file in following location:
grails-app/conf/database.properties

Now i need to read the file and load it as property as below:

```
public static Properties loadProperties(String fileName) {          
    Properties prop = new Properties();                             
    try {                                                           
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        prop.load(inputStream);                                     
    } catch (IOException e) {                                       
        e.printStackTrace();                                        
    }                                                               

    return prop;                                                    
}
```

- When i give fileName as database.properties, it
  displays error as: java.io.FileNotFoundException: database.properties
  while we run.
- On other hand when i give fileName as
  grails-app/conf/database.properties it will run fine in local. But
  when i run in tomcat server as WAR file, it will shows same as above
  error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: database.properties.

Now how can i resolve the above issue and can run my code in both local and tomcat.

Comment: This is not the Grails way to have externalized configuration. Read the docs: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized

Answer (score 1):

You need to revisit the Grails DataSource documentation at http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource.

There's no reason to store a file in the same directory as the Grails config and try to read it explicitly when you can just include the properties you need in your datasource configuration.  You'll be happy that you didn't spend all your effort "reinventing the wheel."